# Javascript security error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

so i created a local web-server with node.js (watch-http-server). When i run below, it runes perfectly within stack's snippet. However, the problem comes when I i run it on the local web

SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "href" on cross-origin object

```js
$(function(){
 alert('load');
});
```

```css
body, html{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: default;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url("../res/background.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.stream-container{
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

 top: 2%;
 left: 5%;
}
.chat-container{
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 
 top: 33%;
 left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title> Twitch Bot </title>
<meta name="author" content="Author">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="stream-container">
    <iframe id = "stream-frame" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=dyarambo" height="300px" width="30px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="chat-container">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="https://www.twitch.tv/lovenpk/chat?darkpopout" height="300px" width="300px"></iframe>
    </div>
    

    <!-- Javascripts below -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="../js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The [cross-origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is being violated.

The problem resides in your usage of the `iframe`:

```
<iframe id = "stream-frame" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=dyarambo" height="300px" width="30px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

> *Error: Permission denied to access property "x"*
>
> There was attempt to access an object for which you have no
>   permission. This is likely an  element loaded from a different
>   domain for which you violated the same-origin policy.

Since your `localhost` is served from a server on a different domain as `player.twitch.tv` you are being prohibited from accessing information on that server. This is an in-browser restriction built into the web.

Additionally, your local web app would also need to be running on the same port as the server that is serving `player.twitch.tv`.

Answer (score 0):

from [MDN cross-origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

`Here are some examples of resources which may be embedded cross-origin:
    Anything with <frame> and <iframe>. A site can use the X-Frame-Options header to prevent this form of cross-origin interaction.`

And I try a test on my pc with a nodejs server listening on localhost:5555, there is no SecurityError.